# retain on [NSDate distantPast] crashes ... sometimes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In the app I'm writing,

```
        NSDate *test = [NSDate distantPast];
        [test retain]; // crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

crashes almost every time on retain, while

```
        NSDate *test = [NSDate date];
        [test retain];
```

does never.

I am puzzled why. The piece of code is called on the main thread through an UI action and I'm running it in the IOS simulator in the debugger. Sometimes it works without crashing. Might it be a concurrency issue? Is there an obvious problem that I am missing or should I try trimming down my application until it works?

**UPDATE:**

```
        NSDate *test = [[NSDate distantPast] copy];
```

crashes as well, while

```
        NSDate *test = [[NSDate date] copy];
```

doesn't. Cleaning the build and restarting the IOS simulator didn't help either.

**UPDATE 2:**

Calling the snippet in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` does not crash. My app must be doing something that messes up the system. I'll post an answer when I find out what.

**UPDATE 3 (SOLVED):**

The offending line was somewhere completely different in my application:

WRONG:

```
- (id)init
{
    lastUpdate = [NSDate distantPast];
}
```

The instance of distantPast gets autoreleased after the execution leaves the init code block. I should have retained it to counter that autorelease.

CORRECT:

```
- (id)init
{
    lastUpdate = [[NSDate distantPast] retain];
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between the two snippets ? I am puzzled too.

Comment: What about if you try `test = [[NSDate distantPast] copy]` instead? Same ownership, but different route.

Comment: @Vince and Abizern. I corrected the snippets. They indeed were the same.

Comment: Likely you are messing up memory somewhere else and the issue is only manifesting itself in the lines you provided. There should be absolutely nothing wrong with retaining `distantPast`, and if you are adamant that there is nothing else wrong in your code then you should submit a bug report.

Comment: I just threw some `NSDate *test = [[NSDate distantPast] copy];` code in a few places in a test project (in response to a UI action), poked at it a dozen times, and got no crashes.  Something fishy going on for you! =[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profile your app with the "Zombies" instrument. When it crashes, you should be able to see the full retain/release history of the rogue object, and from that figure out what went wrong.